# Apply aggregate function on subset of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, average

I have a table that I want to calculate the average of one column but only for the last 10 rows.

```
SELECT AVG(columnName) as avg FROM tableName
```

I cannot apply top directly since this query only returns one row. I need a way to get the latest 10 rows and do the average on them.

Comment: Take the average of an appropriate subquery (by the way, what do you mean by "last ten rows"? Databases do not necessarily have an inherent sense of row order). What's stopping you?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(columnName) FROM
(SELECT TOP 10 columnName FROM tableName ORDER BY ColumnWhichHoldsOrder DESC) A
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select avg(columnName)
from (
   select columnName, 
          row_number() over (order by some column desc) as rn
   from tableName
) t
where rn <= 10;
```